# Hibernate EmptyInterceptor works, but not Interceptor

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, interceptor

I have the following Hibernate Interceptor:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7228720290710296593L;

  @Override
  public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // do some things

    return super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // do some things

    return super.onFlushDirty(entity, id, currentState, previousState, propertyNames, types);
  }

}
```

I'm trying to upgrade by implementing `Interceptor` instead of extending `EmptyInterceptor`, since it is deprecated. My new interceptor is the following:

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomInterceptor implements Interceptor, Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7228720290710296593L;

  @Override
  public boolean onSave(Object entity, Object id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // do some things
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Object id, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {
    // do some things
  }

}
```

Basically, both interceptors do exactly the same operations. However, the first one works, while the second one doesn't. By work, I mean `onSave` and `onFlushDirty` get called when it is expected, while in the second example they simply won't be invoked. So, it should not have anything to do with the operations involved within them. Since `EmptyInterceptor` really does nothing, I don't know what is wrong with the implementation.

**UPDATE 1**

I've just found out that instead of entering my overriden methods, it is simply using `Interceptor` default `onSave` and `onFlushDirty`. How is that possible?

**UPDATE 2**

If I override deprecated methods `onSave` and `onFlushDirty` instead of the valid ones it works.

Comment: According to doc your class must also implement java.io.Serializable.

Comment: @Mar-Z I've also tried implementing it. I've updated the class tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It seemed that the project was using more than one interceptor. For that purpose, a custom interceptor was handling the calls to this `CustomInterceptor`. This handler was extending `EmptyInterceptor`, which made it to call deprecated methods instead of the valid ones. Simply implementing `Interceptor` in this handler made it work.